# Juego de Ahorcado en C

Tags: c, if

Estoy haciendo un juego de Ahorcado en C y hasta ahorita llevo el conteo de las letras dependiendo de la palabra a adivinar que ingrese el usuario, ya tengo una condición que me señala que si la letra que ingrese es igual a alguna de las posiciones de la palabra entonces me va a hacer determinada acción y ahí es donde entra mi duda, cómo puedo lograr imprimir las letras que le atine dentro de mis lineas, y cómo puedo ir restando los intentos que tiene si no le atina a la letra?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int x,y,r,tamano,a;
    char palabra[100],palabra2[100];
    char letra;
    int intentos=5;
    printf ("***********AHORCADO*************\n");
    printf ("Ingrese la palabra a adivinar:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(palabra);
    system ("cls");

    tamano=strlen(palabra);
    printf("\n\n");

    for (x=0;x<tamano;x++)
        {  
         palabra2[x]=95;
        }
    for (x=0;x<tamano;x++)
        {
        printf (" %c",palabra2[x]);
        }

printf ("\nIntentos: %d",intentos);
printf ("\n");
printf ("Ingrese una letra:  ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf ("%c",&letra);

    for (x=0;x<tamano;x++)
        {
        if (letra==palabra[x])
            {
                palabra2[x]=palabra[x];
            }
        else 
        intentos--;
        }
}
```

Comment: Perdón por el formato del código todo revoltoso, no sé como hacerle para que no se vea así jaja

Comment: selecciona el texto del código y presiona ctrl k (o en un editor de código le agregas 4 espacios a cada linea)

Comment: Ya me lo editaron pero aún así gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una solución un poco rebuscada, pero que te servirá:

Inserta esto en tu algoritmo:

```
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy(short x, short y)
{
   COORD pos = { x, y };
   SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pos);
}

void color(WORD col)
{
   SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),col);
}
```

¿Que es lo que hace?
Bueno, el primer procedimiento es un "go to (x,y)", transforma la pantalla en un plano (no literalmente) , llama al procedimiento de la siguiente manera:

```
gotoxy(x,y);
```

*Esto hará que el puntero de la pantalla, vaya a dichas coordenadas de la consola de comandos, a continuación, lo que escribas con* `printf` *comenzará a escribirse desde ese punto de la pantalla de la consola*

Si te preguntas que es el otro, solo establece un color a cualquier cosa que escribas en la consola, para usarlo:

```
color(variable);
```

Y la consola cambiará de color los caracteres y el fondo, de acuerdo al número ingresado, **esto es permanente hasta que vuelvas a usar el comando**

No olvides incluir la librería.

Comment: Entonces el algoritmo lo tendría que incluir dentro de mi ciclor for en donde voy a imprimir la letra, cierto?

Comment: No, puedes poner en cualquier lugar, y podrás re usarlo desde cualquier sitio con solo llamarlo como te mostré arriba, te recomiendo ponerlo fuera del main, ¿se entendió?